# .clearcontents vba has bugs

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I was trying to clear contents of some cells. In the range "Adjs", if the cell's  font is bold, then that row I won't clear, if the cell is not bold. I will clear that entire row..
However it keeps giving me this error when I was running it "Application- defined or object-defined error"
Thank you

```
Sub CL()
  Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  Sheets(1).Select
  For Each c In Range("Adjs").Cells
    If c.Font.Bold = false Then
      Range(c.Offset(0, -6), c.Offset(0, -1)).ClearContents
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Which line does the error occurs? Is the worksheet of `Range("Adjs")` the same as Sheets(1)?

Comment: What is the Address of the offset range? It will fail if **Adjs** is before column G. Add `Debug.Print Range(c.Offset(0, -6), c.Offset(0, -1)).Address` in the loop

Comment: yes,I set a column range name as Adjs.

Comment: And It looks the whole code is wrong. no highlights stop on any line.

Comment: "Adjs" range is (G1:G19)

Comment: So there is no errors now?

Comment: still ..."run-time error '1004' :same error...

Comment: i think you need to unprotect it first.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
Sub CL()
    Dim lCalMode As Long, c As Range
    lCalMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    On Error Resume Next
    With ThisWorkbook.Names("Adjs").RefersToRange
        .Worksheet.Activate
        .Worksheet.Unprotect
        For Each c In .Cells
            If c.Font.Bold = False Then
                With Range(c.Offset(0, -6), c.Offset(0, -1))
                    Debug.Print "Clearing " & .Address
                    .ClearContents
                End With
            End If
        Next
        .Worksheet.Protect
    End With
    Application.Calculation = lCalMode
End Sub
```

Comment: It was my typo when I was typing in here. In my vba it is Font. It is not working...

Comment: I have tried your code...but It is still same error. :(.

Comment: I don't think this spreadsheet is protected. I checked, It is unprotected.

Comment: Try amended code, and you may want to comment out the `.ClearContents`. This will only display the addresses that should be cleared. If all ok, remove the comment and try Step into it by pressing [F8].